# How to plot latitude/longitude hexagons in R when given coordinates in a 'polygon' datatype?

Tags: r, ggplot2, leaflet, ggmap, r-sp

I have done some basic data analysis with the [City of Austin's scooter dataset](https://dev.socrata.com/foundry/data.austintexas.gov/7d8e-dm7r). In this dataset, every scooter ride is given an [id of the geographical hexagon](https://data.austintexas.gov/Transportation-and-Mobility/Citywide-Hexagaon-Grid-500ft-/fpn4-eje4) in which the ride began or ended.

I grouped by hexagon and summed the count of rides and made a csv that you can get like this:

```
austin_hexagon_SO <- read_csv("http://www.sharecsv.com/dl/229ad18b34ffb021189a821a3bcbd5a8/austin_hexagon_SO.csv")

glimpse(austin_hexagon_SO)

# Observations: 2,482
# Variables: 3
# $ orig_cell_id <dbl> 15186, 14864, 14706, 14707, 15019, 14714, 1502…
# $ n            <dbl> 10765, 8756, 8538, 8338, 8291, 8049, 7988, 778…
# $ polygon      <chr> "POLYGON ((-97.735143 30.283413000000003, -97.…
```

Now, I have looked into a bunch of different packages, especially `library(sp)` but I've been unable to bridge the gap from taking a dataframe that looks like this and transforming it to something that base R plot, ggplot, ggmap, or sp can understand and plot.

I'd love to start off with a basic heatmap where the fill aesthetic of the hexagon is scaled to `n`.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

After you read the data frame, the polygons are still just strings (i.e. of class `character`). R doesn't know yet that these strings have a very special format known as `WKT`.

```r
library("readr")
library("tidyverse")

austin_hexagon <- read_csv(
  "http://www.sharecsv.com/dl/229ad18b34ffb021189a821a3bcbd5a8/austin_hexagon_SO.csv",
  # 10 polygons are sufficient for an example
  n_max = 10)
#> Parsed with column specification:
#> cols(
#>   orig_cell_id = col_double(),
#>   n = col_double(),
#>   polygon = col_character()
#> )

glimpse(austin_hexagon)
#> Observations: 10
#> Variables: 3
#> $ orig_cell_id <dbl> 15186, 14864, 14706, 14707, 15019, 14714, 15029, ...
#> $ n            <dbl> 10765, 8756, 8538, 8338, 8291, 8049, 7988, 7787, ...
#> $ polygon      <chr> "POLYGON ((-97.735143 30.283413000000003, -97.735...

# This package contains a function that can handle the conversion from
# WKT polygons to a SpatialPolygons data frame
library("rangeMapper")
#> Warning: package 'rangeMapper' was built under R version 3.5.3
#> Loading required package: RSQLite
#> This is rangeMapper 0.3-4

X <- WKT2SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(austin_hexagon, "polygon", "orig_cell_id")
class(X)
#> [1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
#> attr(,"package")
#> [1] "sp"

plot(X)
```

[image]

```r
library("sp")

# If you want to color by n, first add n to the SpatialPolygons DF
X <- merge(X, austin_hexagon, by = "orig_cell_id")

# There a number of ways to plot spatial polygons; let's use base graphics
# Create a color palette
maxColorValue <- 255
palette <- colorRampPalette(c("white", "red"))(maxColorValue)

plot(X, col = palette[cut(X$n, maxColorValue)])
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>